# Where in the Rails source governs the asset pipeline?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I would love to dig into the rails source that governs the Asset Pipeline, but not sure where to look. ActiveSupport, ActionView, ActionPack, is it a Railtie?

Ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The asset pipeline is technically no longer a core part of Rails 4, it has been extracted out of the framework into: [sprockets-rails](https://github.com/rails/sprockets-rails), based on [sprockets](https://github.com/rails/sprockets), a Rack-based asset packaging system.

Comment: Thanks much! Just what I was looking for.